# How to use dlib in iOS Swift?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, swift2, dlib

I am doing a simple demo project on iOS **using swift and Dlib**. Let's say I already have modified code for extracting facial landmarks using dlib C++ Lib, and I have tested my code in Xcode, which is pretty good(Although the capture is a little slow).

Now, I want to use iPhone front camera to do the device test. I only know C++ and Swift at this time. How to bring them together? What's the recommended method? Do I need to put all functions I need in *.mm files, and invoke them in the Swift code?

Expect to great answers and thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to compile the dlib C++ into xcode (ios) it seems you already have done this can you  tell me how to compile the dlib C++ Into xcode ios, i have tried to compile but i am getting linker errors.

Comment: 1. dlib recalls OpenCV, so first make sure that you embed binary opencv framework in "General" of Xcode. 2. In "build settings" of Xcode, make sure your search path is correct. 3. I suggest you firstly write a simple dlib code in Xcode Mac console, make sure it works, and then you transfer it to Xcode iOS.  Sorry that I reply so late, I hope it helps.